# Why getting 'KeyError' in Python's seaborn syntax?

Tags: python, seaborn, keyerror

I am getting error **KeyError**: 'Drat' on the below syntax:

```
sb.regplot(x='Drat', y='Carb', data=cars, scatter = True)
```

data for this syntax is:

```
cars.head()
Out[54]: 
               Model   Mpg   Cyl   Disp   HP   Drat     Wt   Qsec   Vs   Am  \
0          Mazda RX4  21.0     6  160.0  110   3.90  2.620  16.46    0    1   
1      Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0     6  160.0  110   3.90  2.875  17.02    0    1   
2         Datsun 710  22.8     4  108.0   93   3.85  2.320  18.61    1    1   
3     Hornet 4 Drive  21.4     6  258.0  110   3.08  3.215  19.44    1    0   
4  Hornet Sportabout  18.7     8  360.0  175   3.15  3.440  17.02    0    0   

    Gear   Carb  
0      4      4  
1      4      4  
2      4      1  
3      3      1  
4      3      2
```

Can anyone explain why this error occurs? please.

Comment: I tried your code. Seems to be working fine with me.

Comment: @HarvIpan Thanks a lot for your confirming the code.

Comment: `print(cars.columns)` to check for whitespace in column names